# Help with simple macro for ubuntu/centOS

Tags: scripts, gui

I have always used autoIt for windows for this but i need to do it on ubuntu or centOS now.
Basicly what i want is to send an mouseclick or button after an randomized time example:

~

```
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate") ; hotkey for stopping script

While 1
 Sleep(Random(120000, 180000)) ;waits random between 2 and 3 minutes before sending a left mouse click 
 MouseClick("Left")
 Sleep(Random(60000, 120000)) ; wait random between 1 and 2 minutes to send O
 Send("O")
 Sleep(Random(10000, 20000)) ; waits random between 10 and 20 seconds to send a left mouse click
 MouseClick("Left")
WEnd

Func Terminate()
 Exit
EndFunc
```

~

is there an program wich can do this? i have looked around but i couldn't find something i can understand.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are looking for something similar to autoit, you may want to take a look at [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki).

Comment: @pLumo iv'e found those two earlyer today but i don't think or atleast i cannot find information on it to make random time intervals

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash/1195035 and combine the information  ...

Comment: @pLumo is that possible combining bash with xdotools?

Comment: you should read more than just the first sentence of the first answer ... there is a while-loop with sleep 5, change the 5 with random number and you're fine.

Comment: @pLumo something like this?

~
     #!/bin/bash
     while [ 1 ]; do
      xdotool click 1 &
      sleep $ echo $((60 + RANDOM % 120))
     done
~
?

Comment: `echo` will print the value, you want to add it directly to sleep: `sleep $((60 + RANDOM % 120));`.

Comment: @pLumo thanks dude! it works but i made it random between 10 and 20 seconds and allot of times it disregards the limit of 20 seconds and goes beyond that.How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you usually use a bash script to do something like this. In order to get a mouse click, you need to install `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Now, you can write a simple bash-script. Just run

```
nano bash_script.sh
```

Now paste following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  sleep $((120 + RANDOM % 60))
  xdotool click 1
  sleep $((60 + RANDOM % 60))
  echo '0'
  sleep $((10 + RANDOM % 10))
  xdotool click 1
done
```

Run `sudo chmod u+x bash_script.sh` in order to make your script executable.
Last, you can start your script with

```
sh bash_script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i dont understand any of that, im not great at coding just a simple windows user

Comment: Did you solve your problem yet? Otherwise I'll try to find a solution